# В длине комментария перестали считаться невидимые пробелы

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, нытьё

Раньше можно было набить комментарий [невидимыми пробелами](//unicode-table.com/ru/200B/) до требуемой длины, а теперь стало нельзя. Хотелось бы вернуть...

Вероятно, это как-то связано с недавним [вопросом](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317380/4928642) на metaSO.
Но ведь имя пользователя по-прежнему считается.

PS: Скорее не [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82), а [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, разве только комментария?

Comment: Так вроде в вопросе речь про комментарии.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, как бы да, с заголовком я этого раньше не пытался проделать. Но сейчас в заголовке тоже не учитываются.

Comment: Нет.‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫

Comment: !‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫‪‫

Comment: ‫‪Сложно...‫‪‫‪